# What causes this error: Missing message for key "index.title" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_US

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, struts

I'm just starting with Struts 1.3.  I tested the struts-mailreader-1.3.10.war in Tomcat and everything works fine.  I then unzipped the .war into my workspace for Eclipse and added an Ant build.xml file to the root.  When the build file deploys the war back to the Tomcat container I get the stack below.  Since I'm also new to Ant I'm not sure if this issue would most likely be caused by a file not deployed correctly or is there a properties file I need to add?  I have not been able to find in my project the MessageResources.properties that I have read about on various sites but I'm not sure I need it since the project works without it before I deploy with eclipse and Ant.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Missing message for key "index.title" in bundle "(default bundle)" for locale en_US
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:774)
 org.apache.jsp.Welcome_jsp._jspService(Welcome_jsp.java:126)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.handleAsForward(PerformForward.java:113)
 org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.PerformForward.perform(PerformForward.java:96)
 org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractPerformForward.execute(AbstractPerformForward.java:54)
 org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
 org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
 org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
 org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
 org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
 org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original war (struts-mailreader-1.3.10.war) you would have message resource properties file (resource bundle) in WEB-INF. Once ant builds the war check if it copies this file in the WEB-INF of the deployed application.

Comment: I've narrowed the issue down to the way I've set up the project in eclipse.  When I import the project eclipse is making WEB-INF/src/java the src folder and the struts-config file is looking for the properties without including the java folder.  When trying to set the project up correctly I am having issues making the WEB-INF src folder the src folder if that makes sense.

Comment: Eclipse has its own build mechanism. Ant has its own. You would need to decide which of the two should be building the war. If I were you I would choose ANT, as it would make the project IDE independent for performing builds. In any case you would have to fix ANT script to copy the file to appropriate location while performing the build. Otherwise make relevant change in Eclipse to copy the file into war.